# Function works in onload but not onclick

Tags: javascript

This dead simple stub of a web page will execute the `translate()` function in `onload` but not in the button's `onclick`.  It instead throws "Uncaught TypeError: translate is not a function".

What simple mistake am I making?

```js
function createSvgDef() {
    console.log("createSvgDef()");
}

function translate() {
    console.log("translate()");
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="this-thing.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="this-thing.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="createSvgDef(); translate();">
    <textarea id="input">Hello World!</textarea>
    <button onclick="translate();">Translate</button>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works fine.....

Comment: Interesting, but it's not working for me too.

Comment: Weird case. It is not working for me on Chrome, but works fine on Firefox. If I change the name of the function from `translate` to anything else, it works on Chrome too.

Comment: Change name of function `translate` into something else for example `translate_abcd` and it works on Chrome also. Probably reserved name or some other problem why not working in Chrome.

Comment: Trust me to pick a reserved word not on the list.  Renaming the method has solved it.  Thank you!

Comment: It isn't reserved. It just has a value (in a narrower scope) already. There are hundreds of things like that. The solution is to not use `onclick` *attributes* in the first place.